# While loop in python keeps repeats despite the condition being satisfied

Tags: python, loops

I changed the value of the step but the program keeps asking for my sandwich input over and over. It is supposed to change the value of step so that the program can exit the first while loop and enter the second while loop, but for some reason the first loops keeps repeating.

```
def main():
    order = 0
    step = 0
    total = 0
    while step == 0:
        print ("Welcome to Jeremy's Meat Haven, please pick one drink, one salad, and one sandwitch.")
        print ("Please select a sandwitch by inputting 1, 2, or 3")
        print ("(1) Hamburger  -$1.00") # Print the first option on the menu, and its price, for the user
        print ("(2) Cheeseburger -$1.50") # Print the second option on the menu, and its price, for the user
        print ("(3) Lambburger -$2.00") # Print the third option on the menu, and its price, for the user

        order =  input("What would you like to order? (enter number): ") # Prompt the user for the number on the menu of the item they want to order

        if order == 1:
            total = total + 1
            step = step + 1

        elif order == 2:
            total = total + 1.5
            step = step + 1

        elif order == 3:
            total = total + 2
            step = step + 1

        elif order != 1 or 2 or 3:
            print ("please enter a valid value of 1, 2, or 3")

        while step == 1:
         print ("Please select a drink by inputting 1, 2, or 3")

         print ("(1) milkshake  -$1.00") # Print the first option on the menu, and its price, for the user

         print ("(2) coke  -$1.00") # Print the second option on the menu, and its price, for the user

         print ("(1) lemonade  -$1.00") # Print the third option on the menu, and its price, for the user



    main()
```

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with the indentation here, are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: you are in the wrong tabulator

Comment: Yep your indentation is a bit of a mess so it's hard to say if this is intentional or a bad cut and paste. Please can you fix?

Comment: Is the second while loop supposed to be inside of the first one?

Answer (score 2):

When you get the item number here:

```
order =  input("What would you like to order? (enter number): ") # Prompt the user for the number on the menu of the item they want to order
```

order is a string. You then test it against an integer:

```
if order == 1:   # Not going to be True since order will be '1', '2' or '3'
```

So, test against a string instead:

```
if order == '1':
```

or make order an int:

```
order = int(...)
```

Additionally, you're not seeing the printed error about not entering 1, 2, or 3 because your boolean statement needs work:

```
elif order != 1 or 2 or 3:
```

This will evaluate to True because `if 2` and `if 3` are both True. Try:

`elif order not in ('1', '2', '3')`

Comment: Thank you I completely overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of step in the second while statement. Right now it will loop forever when you enter it.

```
while step == 1:

    print ("Please select a drink by inputting 1, 2, or 3")

    print ("(1) milkshake  -$1.00") # Print the first option on the menu, and its price, for the user

    print ("(2) coke  -$1.00") # Print the second option on the menu, and its price, for the user

    print ("(1) lemonade  -$1.00") # Print the third option on the menu, and its price, for the user

    #ask the user to do something and change the value of step
```

Also, you can change

```
step = step + 1
```

to

```
step += 1
```

which does the same thing, but is easier to read and is more pythonic.